# pip is not using the proxy set by the environment

Tags: http-proxy, pip

I want to set some variables in my system.

Using echo $http_proxy also gives me the correct result, but when trying to access internet through terminal, I am getting the previous proxy and not the one I set.

I checked /etc/environment and found that it still shows the old proxy. How can I change this environment variable?

Manually set these in the terminal

```
export http_proxy="http://11.3.2.212:8080"
export https_proxy="https://11.3.2.212:8080"
export ftp_proxy="ftp://11.3.2.212:8080"
```

Accessing internet from terminal:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Error:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff579aaa668>,
'Connection to 16.34.2.212 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')'
```

16.34.2.212 is the old proxy.

I get the same error if I use:

```
export https_proxy="https://11.3.2.212:8080"; pip install tensorflow
```

or

```
export http_proxy="http://11.3.2.212:8080"; pip install tensorflow
```

OS: CentOS 7

I am using ssh to login to this system. I asked other users of the server. They are able to use these exact same commands to install.

Additional info:

```
type -a pip
```

gives

```
pip is /usr/bin/pip
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy

Comment: @Kusalananda I tried the top two answers. Still getting same error.

Comment: @terdon I have already added the error message. I am not repeating same error message because they are all same.

Comment: No, that's fine. What we needed to see is the commands, no need to repeat the error. But mentioning that both `https_proxy` and `http_proxy` fail with the same error is very relevant.

Comment: Setting it manually really should work (and does on my system). Could `pip` be some sort of alias? What is the output of `type -a pip`?

Comment: pip is /usr/bin/pip is the output I get.

Comment: Those are the exact commands you use, right? No `sudo` or `su -c`?

Comment: `pip` doesn't read `/etc/environment`, that file is only read when you log in.

Comment: @xhienne No. Did not use `sudo` or `su -c`.

Comment: Please check that there isn't anything that would override the proxy settings in your pip configuration files  `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` and `/etc/pip.conf`.